# Can I store user ids with google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to track how individual user navigate through a website. Using Google Analytics I can use custom variables so in theory I can use the user ids to track individual users. However, according to the [terms of service](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html) of Google Analytics I can't use GA to `track, collect or upload any data that personally identifies an individual` (Section 7. privacy). Does a user id classifies as data that personally identifies an individual? I merely want to use it to link the data from Google Analytics with our own data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storing user IDs is *probably* a violation of section 7, but there are other ways around this problem.

Section 7 of the ToS states:

> You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service to track, collect or upload any data that personally identifies an individual (such as a name, email address or billing information), or other data which can be reasonably linked to such information by Google.

While sending Google information that is personally identifiable is simply not permitted, you can instead send an identifier which is *known only to you*. In fact Justin Cutroni (Analytics Evangelist at Google) has confirmed this [in this article](http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/05/05/merging-google-analytics-with-your-data-warehouse/).

I've recently written up my current thinking on this with some a couple of world examples:

"[Identifying your users in Google Analytics while complying with section 7 of the terms of service](http://davidsimpson.me/2013/10/17/identifying-your-users-in-google-analytics-while-complying-with-section-7-of-the-terms-of-service/)"

Comment: unable to open the second link in chrome. The error is "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH"

Comment: That's very odd, it has a "Grade A" in this SSL test report: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=davidsimpson.me

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it does. It doesn't matter what you intent to do or not. The fact that you have the possibilty to map the id back to the person is enough.

Additionally: I'm not a lawyer but I'd say if you are tracking such data (with whatever technical means) it has to be in the terms of your website and signed by the user.

Comment: However, a user id itself does not personally identifies an individual, and the terms do not state that you can't store data that *you* can't map back to the person. It does state explicitely that you can't store data which `which can be reasonably linked to such information by Google`. But I'm not Google and Google can't link that information back to a person. So what exactly in the terms make that I can't store an ID which only *I* can map back to a user account?

Comment: The citation from your question suggested otherwise. This way it might be OK with Google but I'm still sticking to my second point.

Comment: You might want to consult a lawyer and not a programming community ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Personally identifiable information would be something like a name, phone number or email address. You'd be okay to store hashed information about this user in Google Analytics and then decrypt offline. E.g. You can store a hash of the user's name in Google Analytics and then decrypt offline.

You also may want to check you've the correct privacy policy in place and follow these rules: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy

Comment: From the page linked (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy): "You will not upload any data that allows Google to personally identify an individual (such as certain names, Social Security Numbers, email addresses, or any similar data), or data that permanently identifies a particular device (such as a unique device identifier if such an identifier cannot be reset), **even in hashed form**."
(Emphasis is mine.)

I believe that this means that PII cannot be sent to Google Analytics at all, even in hashed form.

Comment: Also, hashing is a one-way operation, so a hash cannot later be decrypted.

Comment: @IntrepidCuriosity, it seems the developer document has been revised and now doesn't contain information about hashing.

Also, you'd create an offline key to "de-hash". E.g. in your database you'd have: '2adc83bfb66efdc08b3d049a160c316a' = John Smith

Answer (score 0):

You can use non obfuscated alphanumeric database identifiers that you might create for your visitors. Another acceptable option is to pass to Google Analytics an encrypted identifier that is based on PII that is not Protected Health Information (as defined under HIPAA), as long as you use the proper encryption level. Google has a minimum hashing requirement of SHA256 and strongly recommends the use of a salt, minimum 8 characters.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/crm-integration#user_id

Comment: The problem with this is, is that's almost mutually exclusive because maximum length of user properties is 36 chars while SHA256 outputs 64 chars